# Do you need reduced row echelon form when finding the null space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, gaussian-elimination

I have heard several people say that you need to put a matrix in *reduced* row echelon form to find a basis for the null space of a matrix. But why does it not suffice to simply go down to row echelon form (not necessarily *reduced* row echelon form) and then get a basis from there?

Comment: If you are given a reduced row echelon form, for example in a true-false question or quick computation problem on an exam, it is certainly simpler to use that.  But nobody *has* to use that. In my own life I have not generally computed a "rref" (except to show students that it can be done), although when I have computed nullspaces my computations are probably in some sense equivalent to identifying a reduced row echelon form. The general problem of computing a basis for a vector space can be solved in many ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more convenient to find the linearly independent rows and columns when your matrix is in reduced echelon form. It is  worth to take the extra steps to go from echelon form to reduce echelon form.

Answer (score -1):

It is not *needed* to convert a matrix to its row reduced echelon form (rref) or even its row echelon form. If you can find the null space i.e., the linear combination of the columns that maps them to the zero vector just by looking at the original *unreduced* form, then you do not necessarily have to convert the matrix to rref. Gaussian elimination and Jordan back-substitution (methods used to convert a matrix to its rref) preserve the null space of the matrix, so it does not matter if you identify the null space using the original matrix or its rref.

We convert a matrix to its rref because its easier (most of the times) to identify the null space using the rref than using the original form.